# Android: How to receive a complete html, with images and css files as string?

Tags: android, image, caching, offline

I'm looking for a way to cache my html, css and images on Android when only on wifi. If not on wifi the application is to read from the cache. I know a way this can be solved on iPhone [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), using Base64 encoding.

So, how to receive a complete html, with images and css files as string, so that I can store it on the phone and display it in offline mode?

**EDIT - RESOLVED**

1. Get the html using `HttpClient`
2. Matching all src and href tags `(src|href)s*=s*\"([^\"]+)\"`
3. Get the file from server and converts it with `Base64`
4. Replaces the filename tag with the converted Base64 string in the html
5. Insert the new html string to a Sqlite database ready for use :)

Comment: How will the HTML be displayed? And at what rate will it be updated?

Comment: Do you have a demo code for this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use HttpClient class to download html file and other related file and store it.

Comment: I have tried using HttpClient and it did just download the html. I need the images and css - files

Comment: i guess you need to parse the html and download related resource your selt.

Comment: How would such a feature be implemented?

Comment: one solution i think is, you can search for address (a), image and other similar tag html tag , resolve the url, download the content with httpclient and then change all those link to local url and save it.

Comment: 1. Grab all URLs from the HTML with this simple regex: /(src|href)="([\w=:\./\-]+)"/  2. Download the images, javascripts and .css files pointed to by the URLs you grabbed. 3. Filter all .css files downloaded through this simple regex: /url\(\s*[\'"]*([^\)]*)[\'"]*\s*\)/ 4. download all resources pointed to by those urls. Keep in mind that you will have to convert all URLs in the HTML to something relative to your new location in the process.

Comment: @parag yeah, look at my question under "EDIT - RESOLVED"